# Login feature working on local but not on Live server in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have deployed my project on a live server; however, it is not functioning as expected. When I click the login button, it redirects me to a local IP address. What might be the cause of this issue? Here are my code snippets for reference:

Here is my Login Form:

```
<!-- Form -->

<form class="form-horizontal mt-3 form-material" id="loginform" action="https://samplesite.edu.jp/school_portal/login-user" method='POST'>
@if(Session::has('success'))
 <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('success')}}</div>
@endif
@if(Session::has('fail'))
 <div class="alert alert-danger">{{Session::get('fail')}}</div>
@endif
@csrf

<!-- The rest of the form (email and app code)-->
</form>
```

This is the route in my web.php:

```
Route::post('/login-user',[LoginController::class, 'loginUser'])->name('login-user');
```

And this is the code on my controller:

```
 public function loginUser(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'application_code' => 'required|min:5|max:20'
    ]);

    $user = UserModel::where('email', $request->email)
                    ->where('application_code', $request->application_code)
                    ->first();
 
    if ($user) {

        $request->session()->put('loginId', $user->seq_id);

        return redirect('dashboard');
    } else {

        return back()->with('fail', 'The email and application code does not match');
    }
}
```

After clicking the login button, it redirects me to this web address:

http://192.168.7.101/school_portal/login

And the error on my form says "Please login first"

Comment: Form action should be an laravel route. You should also check inside your source code to see where the text "Please login first" comes from

Comment: Make sure that the APP_URL in your .env file on the live server is set to your domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a wild guess here but i am thinking you didn't change your `APP_URL` parameter in your .env file. You need to change it to `https://samplesite.edu.jp/school_portal/`. You should also as mentioned in the comment on your question use the route helper to generate URL's.

You now have:

```
<form action="https://samplesite.edu.jp/school_portal/login-user" method="POST">
```

You should use:

```
<form action="{{ route('login-user') }}" method="POST">
```

Now you can check if the route generated is the correct URL, if so, the redirect should be also ok.